# Resolve URI with multiple slashes in relative part

Tags: html, perl, rfc3986

I have to write a script in perl which parses uris from html. Anyway, the real problem is how to resolve relative uris.

I have base URI (base href in html) for example http://a/b/c/d;p?q (let's go through [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.4.1)) and different other URIs:

/g, //g, ///g, ////g, h//g, g////h, h///g:f

In this RFC, section 5.4.1 (link above) there is only example of //g:

"//g"           =  "http://g"

What about all other cases? As far as I understood from [rfc 3986, section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), multiple slashes are allowed. So, is following resolution
correct?

"///g"          = "http://a/b/c///g"

Or what is should be? Does anyone can explain it better and prove it with not obsoleted rfc or documentation?

**Update #1**:
Try to look at this working url - https:///stackoverflow.com////////a/////10161264/////6618577

What's going on here?

Comment: The first two // after the : are part of the scheme (or fixed after the scheme more precisely), not the relative path. The examples are relative paths, based off a starting URL. Otherwise the path is opaque, it is the problem of the webserver to see if `//` means `/` to mean or not (for unix based ones without redirection rules, it will be, but it is not a property of the protocol). Also URIs are kind of superseded by IRIs (RFC3987) so that you even have more stranger cases to take into account, like direction of writing.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek, Re "*The first two // after the : are part of the scheme*", Nit: They are associated with the authority (the host). For example, `http:foo/bar` is a valid URI, and so is `//stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll start by confirming that all the URIs you provided are valid, and by providing the outcome of the URI resolutions you mentioned (and the outcome of a couple of my own):

```
$ perl -MURI -e'
   for my $rel (qw( /g //g ///g ////g h//g g////h h///g:f )) {
      my $uri = URI->new($rel)->abs("http://a/b/c/d;p?q");
      printf "%-20s + %-7s = %-20s   host: %-4s   path: %s\n",
         "http://a/b/c/d;p?q", $rel, $uri, $uri->host, $uri->path;
   }

   for my $base (qw( http://host/a/b/c/d http://host/a/b/c//d )) {
      my $uri = URI->new("../../e")->abs($base);
      printf "%-20s + %-7s = %-20s   host: %-4s   path: %s\n",
         $base, "../../e", $uri, $uri->host, $uri->path;
   }
'
http://a/b/c/d;p?q   + /g      = http://a/g             host: a      path: /g
http://a/b/c/d;p?q   + //g     = http://g               host: g      path:
http://a/b/c/d;p?q   + ///g    = http:///g              host:        path: /g
http://a/b/c/d;p?q   + ////g   = http:////g             host:        path: //g
http://a/b/c/d;p?q   + h//g    = http://a/b/c/h//g      host: a      path: /b/c/h//g
http://a/b/c/d;p?q   + g////h  = http://a/b/c/g////h    host: a      path: /b/c/g////h
http://a/b/c/d;p?q   + h///g:f = http://a/b/c/h///g:f   host: a      path: /b/c/h///g:f
http://host/a/b/c/d  + ../../e = http://host/a/e        host: host   path: /a/e
http://host/a/b/c//d + ../../e = http://host/a/b/e      host: host   path: /a/b/e
```

---

Next, we'll look at the syntax of relative URIs, since that's what your question circles around.

```
relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

relative-part = "//" authority path-abempty
              / path-absolute
              / path-noscheme
              / path-empty

path-abempty  = *( "/" segment )
path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
path-noscheme = segment-nz-nc *( "/" segment )
path-rootless = segment-nz *( "/" segment )

segment       = *pchar         ; 0 or more <pchar>
segment-nz    = 1*pchar        ; 1 or more <pchar>   nz = non-zero
```

The key things from these rules for answering your question:

- An absolute path (`path-absolute`) can't start with `//`. The first segment, if provided, must be non-zero in length. If the relative URI starts with `//`, what follows must be an `authority`.
- `//` can otherwise occur in a path because segments can have zero-length.

---

Now, let's look at each of the resolutions you provided in turn.

`/g` is an absolute path `path-absolute`, and thus a valid relative URI (`relative-ref`), and thus a valid URI (`URI-reference`).

- Parsing the URIs (say, using the regular expression in Appendix B) gives us the following:

  ```
  Base.scheme:    "http"       R.scheme:    undef
  Base.authority: "a"          R.authority: undef
  Base.path:      "/b/c/d;p"   R.path:      "/g"
  Base.query:     "q"          R.query:     undef
  Base.fragment:  undef        R.fragment:  undef
  ```
- Following the algorithm in §5.2.2, we get:

  ```
  T.path:         "/g"      ; remove_dot_segments(R.path)
  T.query:        undef     ; R.query
  T.authority:    "a"       ; Base.authority
  T.scheme:       "http"    ; Base.scheme
  T.fragment:     undef     ; R.fragment
  ```
- Following the algorithm in §5.3, we get:

  ```
  http://a/g
  ```

---

`//g` is different. `//g` *isn't* an absolute path (`path_absolute`) because an absolute path can't start with an empty segment (`"/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]`).

Instead, it's follows the following pattern:

```
"//" authority path-abempty
```

- Parsing the URIs (say, using the regular expression in Appendix B) gives us the following:

  ```
  Base.scheme:    "http"       R.scheme:    undef
  Base.authority: "a"          R.authority: "g"
  Base.path:      "/b/c/d;p"   R.path:      ""
  Base.query:     "q"          R.query:     undef
  Base.fragment:  undef        R.fragment:  undef
  ```
- Following the algorithm in §5.2.2, we get the following:

  ```
  T.authority:    "g"           ; R.authority
  T.path:         ""            ; remove_dot_segments(R.path)
  T.query:        ""            ; R.query
  T.scheme:       "http"        ; Base.scheme
  T.fragment:     undef         ; R.fragment
  ```
- Following the algorithm in §5.3, we get the following:

  ```
  http://g
  ```

**Note**: This contacts server `g`!

---

`///g` is similar to `//g`, except the authority is blank! This is surprisingly valid.

- Parsing the URIs (say, using the regular expression in Appendix B) gives us the following:

  ```
  Base.scheme:    "http"       R.scheme:    undef
  Base.authority: "a"          R.authority: ""
  Base.path:      "/b/c/d;p"   R.path:      "/g"
  Base.query:     "q"          R.query:     undef
  Base.fragment:  undef        R.fragment:  undef
  ```
- Following the algorithm in §5.2.2, we get the following:

  ```
  T.authority:    ""        ; R.authority
  T.path:         "/g"      ; remove_dot_segments(R.path)
  T.query:        undef     ; R.query
  T.scheme:       "http"    ; Base.scheme
  T.fragment:     undef     ; R.fragment
  ```
- Following the algorithm in §5.3, we get the following:

  ```
  http:///g
  ```

**Note**: While valid, this URI is useless because the server name (`T.authority`) is blank!

---

`////g` is the same as `///g` except the `R.path` is `//g`, so we get

```
    http:////g
```

**Note**: While valid, this URI is useless because the server name (`T.authority`) is blank!

---

The final three (`h//g`, `g////h`, `h///g:f`) are all relative paths (`path-noscheme`).

- Parsing the URIs (say, using the regular expression in Appendix B) gives us the following:

  ```
  Base.scheme:    "http"       R.scheme:    undef
  Base.authority: "a"          R.authority: undef
  Base.path:      "/b/c/d;p"   R.path:      "h//g"
  Base.query:     "q"          R.query:     undef
  Base.fragment:  undef        R.fragment:  undef
  ```
- Following the algorithm in §5.2.2, we get the following:

  ```
  T.path:         "/b/c/h//g"    ; remove_dot_segments(merge(Base.path, R.path))
  T.query:        undef          ; R.query
  T.authority:    "a"            ; Base.authority
  T.scheme:       "http"         ; Base.scheme
  T.fragment:     undef          ; R.fragment
  ```
- Following the algorithm in §5.3, we get the following:

  ```
  http://a/b/c/h//g         # For h//g
  http://a/b/c/g////h       # For g////h
  http://a/b/c/h///g:f      # For h///g:f
  ```

---

I don't think the examples are suitable for answering what I think you really want to know, though.

Take a look at the following two URIs. They *aren't* equivalent.

```
http://host/a/b/c/d     # Path has 4 segments: "a", "b", "c", "d"
```

and

```
http://host/a/b/c//d    # Path has 5 segments: "a", "b", "c", "", "d"
```

Most servers will treat them the same —which is fine since servers are free to interpret paths in any way they wish— but it makes a difference when applying relative paths. For example, if these were the base URI for `../../e`, you'd get

```
http://host/a/b/c/d + ../../e = http://host/a/e
```

and

```
http://host/a/b/c//d + ../../e = http://host/a/b/e
```

Comment: Really great explanation. But even this took a certain amount of time to understand and to move on. I'm trying to reproduce that steps by myself. Anyway, it looks like only your answer push me to the right direction.

Comment: There's a limit to how much I'll put in an answer! But I presented my answer in a way that made it easier to learn whatever the reader needed to learn to understand the answer. Glad it worked :)

Comment: You should write a "rfc guide for dummies" :) 
One more question - empty authority  ("") is the same in terms of rfc3986 as undefined?

Comment: No. "*A component is undefined if its associated delimiter does not appear in the URI reference*". `/g` has an undefined authority, and `///g` has an empty one. §5.2.2 specifically checks for an (un)defined one.

Comment: There's no disctinction between an empty path and an undefined path, however.

Comment: Eventually, I've managed to fix bug in huge application which is based on this problem. Thank you! Think about writing guides, blogs, you're pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I was curious what [Mojo::URL](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/URL) would do so I checked. There's a big caveat because it doesn't claim to be strictly compliant:

> Mojo::URL implements a subset of RFC 3986, RFC 3987 and the URL Living Standard for Uniform Resource Locators with support for IDNA and IRIs.

Here's the program.

```
my @urls = qw(/g //g ///g ////g h//g g////h h///g:f
    https:///stackoverflow.com////////a/////10161264/////6618577
    );
my @parts = qw(scheme host port path query);
my $template = join "\n", map { "$_: %s" } @parts;

my $base_url = Mojo::URL->new( 'http://a/b/c/d;p?q' );

foreach my $u ( @urls ) {
    my $url = Mojo::URL->new( $u )->base( $base_url )->to_abs;

    no warnings qw(uninitialized);
    say '-' x 40;
    printf "%s\n$template", $u, map { $url->$_() } @parts
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
----------------------------------------
/g
scheme: http
host: a
port:
path: /g
query: ----------------------------------------
//g
scheme: http
host: g
port:
path:
query: ----------------------------------------
///g
scheme: http
host: a
port:
path: /g
query: ----------------------------------------
////g
scheme: http
host: a
port:
path: //g
query: ----------------------------------------
h//g
scheme: http
host: a
port:
path: /b/c/h/g
query: ----------------------------------------
g////h
scheme: http
host: a
port:
path: /b/c/g/h
query: ----------------------------------------
h///g:f
scheme: http
host: a
port:
path: /b/c/h/g:f
query: ----------------------------------------
https:///stackoverflow.com////////a/////10161264/////6618577
scheme: https
host:
port:
path: /stackoverflow.com////////a/////10161264/////6618577
query:
```

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't explain to me what to do next )

Comment: You've found a bug in Mojo::URL! It doesn't properly follow §5.2.2 of the aforementioned spec. `///g` should produce `http:///g` (not `http://a/g`) and `////g` should produce `http:////g` (not `http://a//g`).  [Demo](https://pastebin.com/z1EWAwep)

Comment: Now, `http:///g` is a useless URI (having a blank authority). It would be interesting to see how web browsers handle `///g`, but it'll have to wait.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug in Mojo::URL, but here's [issue #1269](https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/issues/1269). I think it's following 5.2.2 better than URI because that module changes the host to an empty string when it's a false value. It rests on what you think is between // and / and if you think a blank authority is defined. Is "A component is undefined if its associated delimiter does not appear in the URI reference" the only way to be undefined? That's not what it says, and that only applies to the base.

Answer (score -1):

No - `///g` would seem more equivalent to `/g` . The "dot-segments" `..` and `.` are what is used to navigate up and down the hierarchy with `http` URLs. See also the [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module for handling paths in URIs.

Comment: Yes, it may be simplified by browsers, but is original url valid still?